# How to get rid of this error when starting Tomcat

Tags: maven, tomcat

I am adding some things in an existing *Android app*, which connects to a *Apache Tomcat* server to get information from a database, but some of the changes required that I also make minor changes on the webapp (changing some database fields).
I had never used tomcat, but managed to do the simple changes here and there.

But when I deployed it, I noticed some errors(see the photo).
How can I fix them ?

The app works regardless of them, but the server takes a few more seconds to start up.

P.S.I read somewhere that this means that the server already has these libs, and doesnt need to use the ones from the lib folder of the app ?

[image: Tomcat Error]

Comment: The answer is in the question. Don't deploy the tomcat jars with your application. It obviously already has them.

Comment: How would I stop them from being deployed with the app ?
I am using Eclipse Juno as IDE, with m2e plugin installed.

Comment: Don't put them into WEB-INF/lib. If you use Maven, set the scope of this dependency to provided.

Comment: There isn't any dependency with "tomcat-embed" in it on the pom.xml file !

Comment: Then it's a transitive dependency of another one. Use mvn dependency:tree to find it, or the eclipse pom editor.

Comment: Using the eclipse pom editor : http://i.imgur.com/F2FwGx7.png .
Now what ? :)

Comment: You're using spring boot. So deploy it as a spring boot application rather than a war file, or declare those dependencies explicitely in your app, with the scope provided.